# Flask session empty after domain forwarding to PythonAnywhere, only in Safari (webkit)

Tags: flask, webkit, session-cookies, pythonanywhere, forwarding

I have a PythonAnywhere Flask application, [xtiles.pythonanywhere.com](http://xtiles.pythonanywhere.com).  I have a GoDaddy domain, [xtilesgame.com](http://xtilesgame.com), and GoDaddy is set up to forward the domain to the PythonAnywhere address.  This works fine for Chrome and FireFox, but in Safari (and Midori, both of which are based on WebKit), the Flask session cookie comes back completely empty.  Going straight to [xtiles.pythonanywhere.com](http://xtiles.pythonanywhere.com) in Safari works fine; it's the forwarding that causes trouble.

So: Is there something different I can do in my flask application to support the forwarding?  Or is there some better way to associate the domain with the PythonAnywhere address?  Any idea why it works with some browsers and not others?

(I have the flask application's "secret key" set to a hard-coded value, always the same.  In case it matters, PythonAnywhere has Flask version 0.11.1 by default; I tried it with a virtualenv running Flask 0.12.2 (because that's what I have locally) -- same problem.)

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the GoDaddy domain forwarding uses an iframe and that Safari is blocking cookies for iframes. So you're never getting the cookie.

Comment: Thanks -- that sounds entirely reasonable.  I just changed the GoDaddy DNS settings to forward without masking; I think that should remove the iframe.  I have to wait for the new settings to propagate to the name servers; once I can test it I'll report back.